# Views Load More pagination causes duplication

Tags: ajax, paging, views

I am encountering an issue with Views Load More with Waypoints module. My question is more focused on the next contents that are retrieved. Because there are new contents added to the top, the page 2, for example, now contains items from page 1, thereby showing duplicates. Please see explanation below. How can this be addressed?

[image]

Comment: Sites like deviantArt does not address this at all, for example. Anyway, this is not Drupal issue, this is general design issue. If you have a solution algorithm and you want Drupal **implementation**, then it's something we could help here.

Comment: Hi Molot, thanks! I initially posted this question in ux.stackexchange.com but was directed to post here instead. I hoped to get ideas on how this can be done with Views, and the Views_Load_More module. An idea is that timestamp of first load is captured and passed in exposed filter to ensure that view results are still the "old" ones. But I am having difficulty in programmatically passing the timestamp to the exposed filter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by:

- Setting a JavaScript variable with the current timestamp (`drupal_add_js()` in `hook_preprocess_page()`)
- Appending this value to my pager anchor through JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1) Do not use the LOAD MORE option in views but use a self generated link with the help of global text in the footer. Then this link is going to a second page and then you have the view in a new fresh window. Hopes this helps.

2) You can try if the behavior of the view is the same without Ajax. Sometimes live is a miracle. if so you know that is a ajax issue and not a views issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using Views Random Seed module.

This may occurred due to any of your SORT CRITERIA which is likely the cause of duplicates. So add *Global: Random seed* also as one your sort criteria conditions to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

In Drupal views we have an advanced section .In that Other options we ll find the Query edit that settings into distinct .This may avoid duplicates

Comment: Issue OP asks about is not about that. It's about entries that were pushed from 1-10 range to 11-20 range after 1-10 was displayed bud before user requested 11-20. It has nothing to do with duplicates in *one* query